# Does iterating over an iterator and mutating a value change the value in the collection?

Tags: reference, rust

I have a `HashMap<u32, u32>` and I use it as an iterator:

```
for (key, mut value) in map {
    if value == 0u32 {
        value = 1u32;
    }
    println!("{}", value);
}
```

This compiles and prints out the expected values, but does it actually change the value in the map while I'm iterating it, or am I just shadowing the actual value and the value is written over after the iterator finishes?

Am I correct in assuming that mutating while iterating works with Rust iterators in general?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> does it actually change the value in the map

**No**. In fact; the *map no longer exists*:

```
for (key, mut value) in map { /* ... */ }    
println!("{:?}", map);
```

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `map`
  --> src/main.rs:14:22
   |
7  |     for (key, mut value) in map {
   |                             --- value moved here
...
14 |     println!("{:?}", map);
   |                      ^^^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `map` has type `std::collections::HashMap<u32, u32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

You've *transferred ownership* of the map and all of the keys and values to the iterator. It's gone. Note that the map isn't even declared as mutable, so there's no way you could make changes to it.

If you *wanted* to modify all the values, you could:

```
let mut map: HashMap<u32, u32> = HashMap::new();

for (_key, value) in &mut map {
    if *value == 0u32 {
        *value = 1u32;
    }
    println!("{}", value);
}
```

Note how now we have a *reference* to the keys and values, not the value itself.

> with Rust iterators in general

It depends on what iterators the item exposes. If there's an iterator of mutable references of some kind, then yes.